# Hidden Area underneath twitter navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In the docs of twitter navbar, its written:

"When you affix the navbar, remember to account for the hidden area underneath. Add 40px or more of padding to the . Be sure to add this after the core Bootstrap CSS and before the optional responsive CSS."

What does this mean? Why is there a hidden area? Its because the way twitter did it or that is how its supposed to work? I am relatively new to HTML/CSS/Bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means that as the navbar stays fixed on the top of the page it needs some fixed height (40px) it needs to show all stuff. Then you have to set a top padding to the body of your html page, so that nothing is layouted under the navbar.

May be you should do it before including the responsive css because it itself needs some absolute values for computing the optimal layout.